# Spring:autowired field is null

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, autowired

I need to wire external lib class to my bean,in order to use it as singleton.
.xml config:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.my.MyBean">
 <property name="someLib" value="com.ExternalBean" />
</bean>
```

java bean:

```
@Service
public class MyBean {

    @Autowired
    private ExternalBean externalBean;


    public void setExternalBean(ExternalBean externalBean) {
        this.externalBean = externalBean;
    }
```

Further I use wired variable `externalBean` in public method ,in order not to instantiate it in every method call.
Problem is it `null`.

Do I wire bean correctly?What is mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You have to define the external class as a bean in order to make @Autowired work.

```
<bean id="externalBean" class="some.external.package.ExternalBean">
</bean>

<bean id="myBean" class="com.my.MyBean">
</bean>
```

Also, if you use @Autowired you don't need the setter for it.

Comment: +1. And the property element is useless, since it's autowired. If it was not autowired, its value would have to be an ExternalBean reference, rather than the String "com.ExternalBean".

Comment: loodakrawa,hi ,thank you for point.Strange ,but still doesn't work.It's null.

Comment: @sergionni
Glad to help :)
It can still be null for a various number of reasons. I is difficult for me to guess based on the relatively limited amount of info. I would suggest you to use explicit dependency injection instead of autowiring because you have a larger degree of control in that way. I suggest reading the following: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators

Answer (score 1):

loodakrawa is right. A second thing that can cause a problem is, that you have a xml bean declaration for `myBean` and additional annotated the bean with `@Service`. I guess this will cause trouble as soon as use enable component scan.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better ide ais to use context path scan:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.external.package">
</context:component-scan>
```

Make sure that all these classes are within the package. Then mark both classes with one of the Annotations (`@Repository, @Service, @Component`).

One of the benefits, no setter required.

P.S: If you re using scan base you don't need to declare class as bean, annotations are enough

Comment: danny.lesnik , yes I have component-scan declaration in my .xml and it's correct,but autowired field is still null.I can't mark external lib class.

Comment: do I need component-scan for external lib?

Comment: @sergionni, you can't do it, because the classes of external libreries are not marked with as Repository, Service, Component.